# How to solve this is launch file?

Tags: controls, ros2, canopen

Wanting to launch this command ros2 launch br_test_canopen_config motor_controllers_ros_control.launch.py

And get this error :
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/u20/.ros/log/2023-05-22-16-02-54-208338-u20-VirtualBox-222822
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=SubstitutionFailure("executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7fb6bf6d8640>]' not found on the PATH")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
await self.__process_event(next_event)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
return self.execute(context)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 465, in execute
self._perform_substitutions(context)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 420, in _perform_substitutions
evaluated_parameters = evaluate_parameters(context, self.__parameters)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 164, in evaluate_parameters
output_params.append(evaluate_parameter_dict(context, param))
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 72, in evaluate_parameter_dict
evaluated_value = perform_substitutions(context, list(value))
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in 
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 232, in perform_substitution
return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/substitutions/command.py", line 94, in perform
command_str = perform_substitutions(context, self.command)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in 
return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 232, in perform_substitution
return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py", line 45, in perform
performed_substitutions = [sub.perform(context) for sub in self.__substitutions]
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py", line 45, in 
performed_substitutions = [sub.perform(context) for sub in self.__substitutions]
File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/substitutions/find_executable.py", line 66, in perform
raise SubstitutionFailure("executable '{}' not found on the PATH".format(self.name))
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7fb6bf6d8640>]' not found on the PATH

I was expecting that the node will be launched and working : My question to which part the problem is related , is it related to the python version used or related to something related to the package TextSubstitution object .